# How does the merge sort algorithm go "up the tree"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm having trouble understanding how the recursive merge sort algorithm works, I understand how it theoretically works :
if there's more than one element in an array find its middle and divide the array into 2 smaller sub-arrays and so on until you have 2 arrays of 1 element that are by definition already sorted (base case) then you can merge them using a merging algorithm, then you go up the tree and so on.

I've tried to implement it in python with some print statements to follow step by step and it works but I don't really understand why it works the way it does. I'll describe you my wrong logic:

the algorithm in pseudo code with l being the low index and h the high index :

```
merge_sort(l,h){

if(l < h){
mid = (l+h)//2
merge_sort(l,mid) 
merge_sort(mid+1,h)
merge(l,mid,h)
}

}
```

so for a an arr = [9,3,7,5]

- We call merge_sort(0,3) which is the full array, l=0 , h =3, mid = 1 [9,3,7,5]
- l < h so it calls merge_sort(0,1), l=0,h=1 , mid=0 [9,3]
- l < h so it calls merge_sort(0,0) l=0 h=0 mid =0 [9]

**from here l == h so we don't fulfill the condition l < h and thus  merge_sort doesn't call itself again, for me the algorithm ends here** ( which is obviously wrong ) BUT here it goes upand calls merge_sort(1,1) [3] (right side of the array)  then merge is executed.
After that it goes up again and tackles the right side of the initial array merge_sort(2,3) [7,5] and continues. ( [7] then [5] then merging )

Can someone please explain me why the algorithms continues to call himself after l == n ? I've read some explanations and watch some videos and some even argues merge(l,mid) sort the full first half [9,3]  and merge(mid+1,h) sort the second full half [7,5] which is apparently not how it's working, I'm really confused.

Comment: Typo? `merge_sort(mid+1,l)` -->> `merge_sort(mid+1,h)`

Comment: Yes typo sorry.

Comment: "for me the algorithm ends here": why would it ? What is the function doing when l=h ? (Be as precise as possible.)

Comment: I guess when l == h we have now solved a smaller problem by getting a 1 element array which is by definition sorted, and have sorted half of the previous array we wanted to sort, we can now do the same process with the right part of this previous array and then merge those two halves, we have now sorted the previous array, we then repeat the process until we have sorted the two halves of the initial array + merged them and finally get the answer of "merge_sort(0,n)". I think I get it but have difficulties to visualize how it's executed step by step programatically

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't call itself again, it returns back to it's previous step in recursion, once it finishes the current one.

Here is an example from GeeksForGeeks of a merge sort algorithm, with each step labeled numerically in a sequential order:
[image: merge sort algorithm, with each step labeled numerically in a sequential order]

Answer (score 1):

You can understand a recursive algorithm by *trusting* it. Have a look at the annotation below (`!` starts a comment):

```
merge_sort(l,h) {

if (l < h) {
    mid = (l+h)//2
    merge_sort(l,mid) ! If merge_sort does its job, the array is now sorted from l to mid
    merge_sort(mid+1,h) ! If merge_sort does its job, the array is now sorted from mid+1 to h
    merge(l,mid,h) ! If merge does its job, the array is now sorted from l to h
}
else { ! If l==h, the array is already sorted from l to h
}
```

Now you can see that if we call the function with some values of `l` and `h`, it will return a sorted array, by calling itself on parts of the array, each time returning them sorted. The whole construction works because the size of the subarrays goes decreasing across the levels of calls, and always reaches 1, causing an immediate return to the calling level.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article, it provides clear explanation:
https://medium.com/@ruchi961/a-complete-step-by-step-visual-tutorial-to-merge-sort-with-implementation-in-python-f7beff7f7e54

After the l<h condition fails i.e. it is false it returns back to the calling line. the function which called it and recursivley back returning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).